# Javascript OOP visibility

Tags: javascript, canvas

Hi guys I have this code

```
class Player {
                        constructor(posX, posY, spdX, spdY, width, height, image){
                            // Vytvoření hráče
                            this.posX = posX;
                            this.posY = posY;
                            this.spdX = spdX;
                            this.spdY = spdY;
                            this.width = width;
                            this.height = height;
                            this.image = image;
                        }     
                        // Draws player
                        draw(){
                            var imageObj = new Image();
                            imageObj.src = this.image;
                            ctx.drawImage(imageObj, testPlayer.posX, testPlayer.posY);
                        }
                        jump(){
                            this.move('up');

                        }
                        // Move
                        move(direction){
                            // Returns false if fails
                            switch(direction){
                                case 'right':
                                    this.posX+= this.spdX;
                                    break;
                                case 'left':
                                    this.posX-= this.spdX;
                                    break;
                                case 'up':
                                    this.posY-= this.spdY;
                                    break;
                                case 'down':
                                    this.posY+= this.spdY;
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    return false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

I have problem in jump method.
When I want to jump I must go up and down, but how can I do that after time.
Because I tried to `setTimeout(function(){})` but inside that function keyword this cant see method move. And if I do `setTimeout(this.move('down'),500)` it doesnt work. So any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the function to have the correct context. One simple way would be to use ES6 arrow functions ([caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions)). They will preserve the `this` context from when you originally defined the function:

```
setTimeout(()=>{this.move('down')}, 500)
```

Or if you want to use regular functions, use Function.prototype.bind() to bind the `this` context. This way, when the function is eventually called, the context is the `this` from when you called .bind(this)

```
function goDown(){this.move('down')}
setTimeout(goDown.bind(this))
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `setTimeout`'s `callback` causes the value of `this` to change.

You can preserve `this` by doing:

```
var that = this;
setTimeout(function () {
    that.move('down');
}, 500);
```

Comment: Hi thanks that works, I will mark as solved after 6 mins

Comment: Good.  If you are using babel, or are targeting ES6 browsers, I would recommend using @James Kraus's answer since it is cleaner.